# Eu ocultei uma div, como faço para trazer ela de volta?

Tags: javascript

Eu estou tentado criar uma frase em um HTML q fica oculta, mas ela aparece quando uma função é ativada.

O código q eu usei para ocultar a div q contém a frase foi:

```
document.getElementById('cal').style.display = "none";
```

(coloquei ele no começo do script)

Assim a frase na div ficou oculta. Mas como eu faço para mostra ela novamente assim q eu ativar uma função, como por exemplo apertar um botão?

Answer (score 1):

Basta alterar o estilo display para o default que é `block`:

```
document.getElementById('cal').style.display = "block";
```